# Optimal processor number in multithreaded application

Tags: bash, multithreading, terminal

I am a biologist doing a informatic analysis on evolving bacteria and I came across a code line of a bioinformatic pipeline that requires the user to input the 'Number of processors to use in multithreaded steps'. I understand the theory behind this, as the more processors, the faster my analysis. As this is a quite intensive analysis the pipeline suggests to use 8. My question is, is theere a limit to how many I should use? I understand that there is a maximum, as in a number of threads after which more pararelization will not make the analysis faster. This is though not a limitation, as it doesn't affect the data itself, just unecessary. My question is, if I were to assign a very high number of processor, would this slow/block my computer in any way? I am not a computer exeprt so I am not sure.

Thank you,
Pesco

No problems yet as I have only run this with one thread, which takes more than a day to run.

Comment: assuming your code is cpu intensive then you'll want to limit your max parallelization to something near/below the max number of cores/threads available on your machine; whether you count cores or threads will depend on your physical processor chip(s) (eg, not all threads are created equal), and you'll want to leave some cpu resources available for other processes (eg, background OS processes, encryption/decryption processes if processing encrypted data, etc); if you spawn 'too many' threads then you'll likely slow down your overall process due to cpu contention/bottlenecks

Comment: if your processing is not cpu intensive then you may be able to bump up the number of parallel processes to some extent, but then you'll also need to look out for other potential bottlenecks, especially network and/or disk throughput; determining the optimum number of parallel threads is going to come down to a bit of trial-n-error to see what works best on your specific hardware; keep an eye on cpu, disk and network utilization to understand where you've got physical limits

Comment: ... and if your processes eat up a lot of memory then obviously (?) you'll also need to monitor memory usage, to include watching out for excessive paging (to 'slow' disks)